# Define region in x++

Tags: axapta, x++, region, dynamics-365-operations

I've developed some new features in x++ with visual studio 2015. I have noticed that I cannot collapse If or else If statement. I can collapse and expand the method's body. I need something similar to the region in C# which enables you to separate related blocks of the code. I cannot use region in x++. I do not know that It is because of the language or because of the version of the IDE i.e, visual studio 2015.

If x++ does not support defining region please introduce me some solutions.

Comment: Take a look at [Make #region available in X++](https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/idea/?idea=ID0001827)

Comment: @FH-Inway Thank you.